# Problems with triggers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-trigger

I have to create tables and triggers to make bank account movements. I have done some, but I'm stuck at the balance one. I have these tables:

Here I just insert the info about the transactions, the description says what I'm doing (deposit 50, withdraw 20, etc.), `D` means deposit and `W` means withdraw.

```
CREATE TABLE transactions
(account VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (),
description varchar (30) NOT NULL,
type ENUM ( 'D', 'W') NOT NULL,
value DECIMAL (7,2) NOT NULL
);
```

I've done a trigger that says which users make the transactions and other info. Later I found a problem.

I have this table called balance, where I need to have the account number and the current balance.

```
CREATE TABLE balance
(Account VARCHAR (10) PRIMARY KEY,
balance DECIMAL (7,2) default 0 NOT NULL 
);
```

So I've made the following trigger, but it doesn't do anything.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER BALANCE_AI after insert on transactions for each row 
begin 
IF NEW.type = 'D' THEN UPDATE balance SET balance = balance + new.value WHERE account = new.account  ;
ELSE UPDATE balance set balance = balance - new.value where account = new.account;
end if;
end // 
DELIMITER ;
```

I don't see how can I update the balance on a determined account or insert and update the balance in the table balance.

I also tried this way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER balance_AI after insert on transactions for each row 
begin 
 UPDATE balance set balance = balance + new.valor where account = new.account;
 insert into balance values (new.account,balance) ON DUPLICATE key update account = account ;
end // 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: At what point do you create the balance for an account - is at at account creation or do you need to create it when the first transaction happens. (this trigger expects balance exists)

Comment: I tried putting the balance on default 0 at the balance table but it doesn't work either because it just let the balance at 0 all the time. So i don't really understand what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I had assumed that the 'after insert on movement' was a typo since you 'CREATE TABLE transactions' - but maybe not?

Comment: I had put after insert because i need to update the balance after any deposit or withdraw so i think it should be an after insert at the transactions table, maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: The trigger is on a table that does not exist ! please read my last comment again.

Comment: Sorry i just fixed the question, the table is the same but it had different names beacuse i didn't translate both parts (trigger and table names). The problem still there, it stills putting 0 balance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem - see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aHiznkWeCCbGp2ZkyQB2GG/0 note I have added an existence check.

Comment: I see what u mean now, but i dont understand why u put: (select 1 from balance b)

Comment: That's all that an existence check requires.

Comment: is it the same than select (*) from etc ?

Comment: 'Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it could begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: I get you now, thank you very much! How can i rate your reply? i'm just new here haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only update a row which exists - test that a balance exists and create if it does not.

```
drop table if exists transactions,balance;

CREATE TABLE transactions
(account VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (),
description varchar (30) NOT NULL,
type ENUM ( 'D', 'W') NOT NULL,
value DECIMAL (7,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE balance
(Account VARCHAR (10) PRIMARY KEY,
balance DECIMAL (7,2) NOT NULL
);

drop trigger if exists t;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER t after insert on transactions for each row 
begin 
if not exists(select 1 from balance b where b.account = new.account) then
    insert into balance values (new.account,0);
end if;

IF NEW.type = 'D' THEN 
    UPDATE balance SET balance = balance + new.value WHERE account = new.account  ;
ELSE 
    UPDATE balance set balance = balance - new.value where account = new.account;
end if;
end // 
DELIMITER ; 

insert into transactions (account,description ,type ,value) values (1,'aaa','d',10);
insert into transactions (account,description ,type ,value) values (1,'aaa','d',20);
insert into transactions (account,description ,type ,value) values (1,'aaa','w',10);

select * from balance;

+---------+---------+
| Account | balance |
+---------+---------+
| 1       |   20.00 |
+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```